# PostgreSQL initdb permission denied but owner is postgres

Tags: macos, postgresql, macports

I am trying to install postgresql90 with macports. I keep getting this weird error when trying to run initdb:

```
sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/initdb -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql90/defaultdb'
```

returns this error:

```
sh: /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/initdb: Permission denied
```

So I am thinking, "Ok well maybe the permissions on initdb are busted". Then I do:

```
sudo ls -l /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/initdb
```

and get back:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 postgres  postgres  66952 25 Sep 10:06 /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/initdb
```

So I have the right permissions on initdb. I also checked defaultdb to see the permissions and they say the owner is postgres as well...

Comment: make sure that postgres user has permissions all the way down the  directory tree.( /opt , /opt/local, /opt/local/lib, etc..)

Comment: try `strace`ing the initdb command and see what the last system call which got an EPERM error is.

Comment: You used `sudo ls -l`. What does `ls -l` without `sudo` report? You should not need `sudo` just to list permissions.

Comment: It says Permission denied without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory `/opt/local/var/db/postgresql90/defaultdb`. It either doesn't exist, or the permissions of the parent directory aren't correct. Run the following:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql90
```

Comment: Alright. defaultdb exists and the permissions are correct.

Comment: is defaultdb a file or a directory?

Comment: It is a directory. It has a bunch of .conf files in it and pg_* files.

Answer (score 0):

A plausible explanation would be that the [sudoers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html) file is configured with NOEXEC in a way  that programs launched with `sudo` cannot themselves execute other programs. *Permission denied* is exactly what you'd get in this case.

Otherwise, another thing to check is if postgres has been installed on a partition that would be mounted with the `noexec` attribute.

Comment: Is that the nature of the sudo su command? Also I checked the /etc/sudoers and it is empty. Do I need to add an alias for the postgres user?

Comment: I don't know much about MacOS, but an empty /etc/sudoers file looks suspicious to me. The stock /etc/sudoers of my OSX 10.8 has 45 lines, especially this one: `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` that I believe is essential for normal usage.

Comment: Well everything else is functioning normally. I even validated the /etc/sudoers file with visudo and it said everything was valid.